# Using if statement in .htaccess file

Tags: regex, .htaccess, preg-match

using basic regex code in .htaccess file, to remove .php extension from site url, like this:

```
# Externally redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

##Internally redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

This works fine,but I also have mail.php file, for sending Emails, and can't post data to this file,because of rules from .htaccess, that path is like this:
www.site/mail instead www.site/mail.php.

So, is there way to set in .htaccess something like:

If url is: www.site/mail.php don't use rule for cutting extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your first rule shouldn't remove `.php` for any `POST` request otherwise you will loose all `POST` data. You can fix it using:

```
# Externally redirect if not POST request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]

##Internally redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```